# Access gradle Android plugin inside custom plugin written in Kotlin

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm writing a custom Gradle plugin which should be able to access the configuration parameters from the Android plugin.

I can do certainly do this from a groovy plugin (which is my current code):

```
MyPlugin.groovy:

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
              variant.registerJavaGeneratingTask( // all the right parameters
```

My problem is that I don't want the plugin to be in Groovy, I want it using Kotlin.
Simply typing `project.android` in Kotlin does not work, as far as I understand I would need to write something similar to what's below:

```
MyPlugin.kt

import com.android.build.gradle.AndroidBasePlugin

class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
         val android = target.plugins.findPlugin(AndroidBasePlugin::class.java)
          // and call android here
```

My main problem is that that import `import com.android.` does not exist.
I tried adding lots of different dependecies on build.gradle.kts, like example `implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1")` but nothing gives me access to it.

questions:

1. is that the right approach?

case:
  (yes) 2. How do I import and use it?
  (no)  2. What is the right approach?

tl;dr:

how to write `project.android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->` inside a Gradle Kotlin plugin

**edit:**

@tim_yates answer worked perfectly. To whom is interested, here is the final code.

build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1")
    ... my other dependencies
}
```

package-name/MyPlugin.kt:

```
import com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension
import com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant
      (...)
  override fun apply(target: Project) {
    val android = target.extensions.findByType(AppExtension::class.java)
    android?.applicationVariants?.configureEach {
      configureVariant(target, this)
    }

  private fun configureVariant(...) { // register my taks there
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you'll need is something like this:

```
        project.extensions.configure<AppExtension>("android") {
            it.applicationVariants.all {
                it.registerJavaGeneratingTask( // all the right parameters
            }
        }
```

And you'll need the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` dependency as you say.

Why it's not being recognized, I'm not sure...  Are you writing a standalone plugin?  If so, what you have works...  If it's an inline plugin in a buildSrc folder, then you'll need to add the lib to the buildSrc build

Comment: hi Tim, thanks for the reply. It's just in the buildSrc folder. I try addind to the buildSrc folder build.gradle.kts dependency. Can you just confirm to me, it is a 'implementation' dependency, right? I'll give a try on Monday when I'm back at "work, but home office because of corona".

Comment:  you're stronger willed than I am... So hard to not work all the time with a home office

Comment: Thanks, it all worked at the end. I guess AndroidStudio was tired on Friday and didn't want to find the dependency, but on Monday it worked no problems ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ .   I edited my question with the final code. Yeah having a kid at home helps to not work on the weekend :D